# MATLAB round function - how does it round .5 up or down?

Tags: matlab

How does MATLAB's round function work with .5? Like 5.5? Does it round up to 6, or round down to 5? The Mathworks page talking about this function says nothing about this, and the example doesn't help either!

Here is the mathworks page for the MATLAB round function:

[mathworks round function page](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/round.html)

Comment: I work for The MathWorks, and I just reported this to our doc staff.

Comment: Great! I did click the "Was this information helpful?" and I said "No." and then filled out the form explaining why. Thanks for reporting it! I am surprised this wasn't caught before. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Variables) knows:

> round(X): round to nearest integer,
>   trailing 5 **rounds to the nearest
>   integer away from zero**. For example,
>   round(2.5) returns 3; round(-2.5)
>   returns -3.

There's a little more information on this scheme (Round half away from zero), and many others, in the article on [rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Comment: Let the wars begin between that banker's rounding people and the away from zero people...

banker's rounding = always round to an even number digit (0,2,4,6,8) to facilitate any division later

away from zero = always round up in an absolute sense and apply the sign later.

Answer (score 4):

```
>> round([-0.5 0.5])

ans =

    -1     1
```

Answer (score 3):

please type 'round(0.5)' in matlab... more efficient than writing on here

Answer (score 3):

This [Rounding Functions Collection](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40286-rounding-functions-collection) that is available on MATLAB Exchange might be of interest as well. It includes M-files/code for several rounding methods that are not included with MATLAB, and a pdf illustrating these together with the standard MATLAB rounding methods.