# Is there a C rounding function like MATLAB's round function?

Tags: c, matlab, rounding

I need a C rounding function which rounds numbers like MATLAB's round function. Is there one? If you don't know how MATLAB's round function works see this link:

[MATLAB round function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597197/matlab-round-function-how-does-it-round-5-up-or-down)

I was thinking I might just write my own simple round function to match MATLAB's functionality.

Thanks,

DemiSheep

Comment: Why can't you write such one by yourself?

Comment: Because you don't write yourself what's provided by the standard library.

Comment: +1 for a seeming simple question which generated a lot of good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't a `round()` function in the standard library, you could, if dealing with floating-point numbers, arbitrarily evaluate each value, analyze the number in the place after the place you want to round to, check to see if it's greater, equal-to, or less-than 5; Then, if the value is less than 5, you can `floor()` the number you're ultimately looking at.  If the value of the digit after the place you're rounding to is 5 or greater, you can proceed to having the function `floor()` the number being evaluated, then add 1.

I apologize for any inefficiency tied to this.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this. If the value is greater than .5, wouldn't I just do ceil()? How would I check the decimal place? Maybe cut off the whole number then check if the decimal number is greater or less than .5?

Comment: If you do something like break a number like 5.321 into an array that holds 4 elements, each containing a number within your 5.321 number, then you could, if you wanted to round to the nearest whole number, evaluate 3 alone. Look up "arbitrary precision arithmetic." D.E Knuth wrote some text on the subject in "The Art of Computer Programming." I believe it was Volume 2 where he spoke of it.  Anyway, you'd basically convert 5.321 into a string, then treat each character (excluding the decimal point) as its own value (first you'd convert each character into a number using something like atoi()).

Comment: This is about the worst way you could go about it, especially since there *are* plenty of options in the standard library. (You *could* have checked before writing the answer.) The scary thing is that this answer actually got accepted...

Answer (score 8):

This sounds similar to the [round()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/round.html) function from math.h

> These functions shall round their
>   argument to the nearest integer value
>   in floating-point format, rounding
>   halfway cases away from zero,
>   regardless of the current rounding
>   direction.

There's also [lrint](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/lrint.html)() which gives you an int return value, though lrint() and friends obey the current rounding direction - you'll have to set that using [fesetround](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fegetround.html)() , the various rounding directions are found [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/fenv.h.html).

Comment: Well, `round()` also does obey `fesetround()`, as well as a multitude of other functions that cover any combination of parameter and return type. `round()` is only special in sofar as that it's the only function from the bunch that doesn't have a 'l' or 'f' appended or prepended...

Comment: The docs explicitly state that round/roundf/roundl does not care for the current rounding direction. math function without a f or l suffix generally takes a double as argument.

Comment: Whoa. Thank you, I missed that little detail (of round/roundf/roundl not honoring the <fenv.h> settings.)

Answer (score 3):

No, C (before C99) doesn't have a `round` function. The typical approach is something like this:

```
double sign(double x) { 
    if (x < 0.0)
        return -1.0;
    return 1.0;
}

double round(double x) { 
    return (long long)x + 0.5 * sign(x);
}
```

This rounds to an integer, assuming the original number is in the range that can be represented by a `long long`. If you want to round to a specific number of places after the decimal point, that can be a bit harder. If the numbers aren't too large or too small, you can multiply by 10<sup>N</sup>, round to an integer, and divide by 10<sup>N</sup> again (keeping in mind that this may introduce some rounding errors of its own).

Comment: Erm... C *does* have a round() function.

Comment: C (at least c99) surely has round/roundf/roundl  - as well as lrint/llrint and similar.

Comment: C99 does -- but C89/90 most assuredly does *not*. Given the number of implementations that are still C89/90, knowing how to do it on your own is still quite useful.

Comment: Alas, squire, time hath moveth on. When someone asks a C question, I assume he's referring to a halfways up-to-date implementation.

Comment: Alas knave, time moveth slowly. Based on actual implementations, assuming anybody's using C99 is pretty silly. Neither of the "big 2" (Gnu and Microsoft) is even *close* to full compliance with C99. pcc is in the paradoxical position of implementing virtually all new C99 features, but still missing lots of crucial C89/90 features. The only reasonably complete implementation of C99 easily available is Comeau with Dinkumware's C99 library. I've been a Comeau user for years, but I'm well aware of how few others are.

Comment: From that standpoint, we shouldn't be answering C++ questions at all because there is only *one* implementation (Comeau, again, or rather its EDG frontend) that's implementing C++ (98) completely. ('export'... my pet peeve.) I have somewhat of a problem with blanket statements like "given the number of implementations..." or "not even *close* to full compliance". Can you say something on the status of rounding support? If not, I feel your statements are misleading.

Comment: @DevSolar: It depends on the library, not the compiler. The one Microsoft distributes doesn't. With Gnu, the library you get depends on the port you use. For example, on Windows cygwin does have rounding support, but MinGW doesn't (or didn't when I last looked anyway). On other systems, the names change but the situation doesn't -- at least from what I've seen, there's probably about a 40:60 split between having it and not.

Comment: @DevSolar: as far as answering C++ question goes, I take about the same position as I do with this: yes, `export` is in the standard, but no, I don't assume that most people have it. If I mention `export`, I usually say something like: "In theory, you should use `export`, but most C++ implementations don't have that, so you need to put all template definitions in headers."

Comment: Still, the statement "C doesn't have a round function" is plain wrong, and misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the standard header `<fenv.c>`, specifically the `fesetround()` function and the four macros `FE_DOWNWARD`, `FE_TOWARDZERO`, `FE_TONEAREST` and `FE_UPWARD`. This controls how floating point values are rounded to integers. Make sure your implementation (i.e., C compiler / C library) actually support this (by checking the return value of `fesetround()` and the documentation of your implementation).

Functions honoring these settings include (from `<math.h>`):

- `llrint()`
- `llrintf()`
- `llrintl()`
- `lrint()`
- `lrintf()`
- `lrintl()`
- `rint()`
- `rintf()`
- `rintl()`
- `llround()`
- `llroundf()`
- `llroundl()`
- `lround()`
- `lroundf()`
- `lroundl()`
- `nearbyint()`
- `nearbyintf()`
- `nearbyintl()`

depending on your needs (parameter type and return type, with or without inexact floating point exception).

**NOTE**: `round()`, `roundf()` and `roundl()` do *look* like they belong in the list above, but these three do **not** honor the rounding mode set by `fesetround()`!!

Refer to your most favourite standard library documentation for the exact details.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you are looking for something like [floor and ceil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and you shall find them in `<math.h>`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation specifies

> Y = round(X) rounds the elements of X to the nearest integers.

Not the plural: as per regular MATLAB operations, it operates on all elements of a matrix. The C equivalents posted above only deal with a single value at once. *If* you can use C++, check out [Valarray](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/). If not, then good ol' for loop is your friend.