# Convert 4 doubles to 4 ints with Intel SIMD instructions

Tags: c, simd, avx

I have four double-precision floating point numbers in a `__m256d` double-precision floating point register.  I want to convert them to four 32-bit integers and have the result be in a `__m128i` single-precision integer register.  I want the conversion to be the same as the C/C++ (int) casting:

```
int tmpInt = (int) tmpDouble;
```

What is the Intel SIMD instruction for this?

Comment: See [`_mm256_cvtpd_epi32`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_cvtpd_epi32&expand=1672).

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091422/avx-sse-round-floats-down-and-return-vector-of-ints

Comment: @PaulR For C/C++ style casting (i.e., truncating) of course `_mm256_cvttpd_epi32`